# Giving each span a individual line-height?

Tags: html, css

I am creating a small chat application. The chat bubble are made with span. This is the CSS of the chat bubble:

```
user1
{
    float: right;
    margin-right: 20px;
    background: #4696E6;
    padding:7px;
    z-index:0;
    line-height: 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    max-width:80%;
    align-content:space-around; 
    line-height:15px;
    font-size:15px;
    word-break: break-all;
    -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(3px 3px 3px #222);
    filter:         drop-shadow(3px 3px 3px #222);
    margin-top:10px;
}
```

I gave a `line-height` to the parent div, so that the chat bubble, are presented in a nice look.
But the problem is when a span has more text, which exceeds the parent div's `line-height`, the other spans are affected.  [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/2ufy3bry/)
Can anyone help me out? Thanks you.

Comment: Why don't use the div for the bubbles? Span is inlined HTML element by its definition, so line-height isn't a solid solution.

Comment: Why are you trying to use an *inline* element to affect the line-height?

Comment: you can only have 1 id on a page.

Comment: What element can I use instead of `span` ?

Comment: How about a `p`? A bubble is a paragraph, right?

Comment: @Aetherus I tried `p`

Comment: Change all `<span>`s to `<p>`s, remove all `<br>`, and add `clear: both;` to your css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change id to class and use this. Notice `clear:right;`

```
.user1
{
    clear:right;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 20px;
    background: #4696E6;
    padding:7px;
    z-index:0;
    line-height: 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    max-width:80%;
    align-content:space-around; 
    line-height:15px;
    font-size:15px;
    word-break: break-all;
    -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(3px 3px 3px #222);
    filter:         drop-shadow(3px 3px 3px #222);
    margin-top:10px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gqcckaxL/